# How to combine two columns using some conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr

I know that this is not the big trouble but I'm juts new to this. I have this output obtained from merging two dataframes. Each one has a column that corresponds to the sex for each participant of an event.

| Sex.x | Sex.y |
| --- | --- |
| M | M |
| F | F |
| F | M |
| M | M |
| F | F |
| M | M |
| *NA* | M |
| F | F |

Desired output: the two columns mixed in one that has "?" when their two values doesn't match and that conserves the only value if there is a NA in the adjacent cell.

| F_Sex |
| --- |
| M |
| F |
| ? |
| M |
| F |
| M |
| M |
| F |

I was trying to do it with dplyr package but I just get to this code. I know I need to use if_else but after many tries, I have nothing.

```
all_data1 <- all_data %>% unite(F_sexo, c(sexo.x, sexo.y), sep = "-", remove = TRUE)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea. Use `coalesce` first to get the rows with only one `NA` to have the correct sex. And then use an `ifelse` to change those rows with different sexes to `?`.

Notice that if you have a row with both columns are `NA`, this solution will return `NA`. Please make sure this is the behavior you want.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Sex = coalesce(.$Sex.x, .$Sex.y)) %>%
  mutate(Sex = ifelse(Sex.x != Sex.y & !is.na(Sex.x) & !is.na(Sex.y), "?", Sex))
dat2
#   Sex.x Sex.y Sex
# 1     M     M   M
# 2     F     F   F
# 3     F     M   ?
# 4     M     M   M
# 5     F     F   F
# 6     M     M   M
# 7  <NA>     M   M
# 8     F     F   F
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Sex.x  Sex.y 
M  M                
F  F
F  M
M  M
F  F
M  M
NA M
 F F", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution. The data is assigned as `df`.

```
df %>% mutate(F_sex = case_when(Sex.x == Sex.y ~ Sex.x,
                                TRUE ~"?"))
```

or

```
df %>% mutate(F_sex = case_when(is.na(Sex.x) ~ Sex.y,
                                is.na(Sex.y) ~ Sex.x,
                                Sex.x == Sex.y ~ Sex.x,
                                TRUE ~"?"))
```

Comment: `Sex.x == NA` will never be `TRUE`, same for the next line. Did you mean to use `is.na(Sex.x) ~ Sex.y` instead?

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans, you are right, I should scrape the table and try the code. Edited the answer.